# Converting VMAP0 VPF format Into a readable file format in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, arcgis

I have a Vector Map VPF format that seemed to contains so many files and folders. 
I was trying to read that and use it in a UWP Universal application so I have an offline map.

I could not use it into MapControl so I downloaded ESRI ArkGIS .Net Library, I tried it out and still not able to read the VMAP0 Format.

I thought I can convert the format, maybe to shapefile or GeoDatabase or any supported format that could be use within UWP.

after looking around I found GDAL OGR tool/Lib but seemed to be complicated.

My questions:

Do I have to convert the VMAP0 files one by one?

Is there any better tool?

Is there any recommendations?

The directory of VMAP contains so many files:

[image]

Comment: Full source code solution posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/jsanalytics/VMap0), [YouTube](https://youtu.be/NoIN8iUL3zU) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/TradePattern). Enjoy!

Comment: Not what I needed although seemed great, how to read shapefiles, eventually after I convert VMAP0 files. I only have VMAP0 & VMAP1 files and I need a way to convert it into shapefiles and do what you have done.

Comment: You should know by now that VMAP files are readily available in shape file format.